# How can we derive more from domain diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

If we imagine we are given with a domain diagram and we also have a use case.

I am struggling to understand, what exactly can we derive?

Ex domain model, found on google.

[image: domain model]

I want to get to the interaction diagrams as a result.

I think the path is, system sequence diagrams -> operation contracts -> interaction diagrams

I just dont get the logic of how to derive all this from a domain diagram because on communication diagrams we can have instance creations that comes out from no where.

Can anyone explain how to derive all this from a domain diagram (if there are steps)?

Answer (score 3):

This domain model represents the static structure of your domain. It does not give any information about its dynamics (how it behaves/changes over time). Sequence diagrams and interaction diagrams model the dynamics. They cannot be derived from the domain model.

In your question, you wrote: "We also have a use case". A use case gives information about the dynamics, so maybe you can derive the sequence/interaction diagrams from the use case.